# In Microsoft Access, how do I export only the currently visible record of a form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, pdf

I have a simple database and a form reflecting one individual record at a time, as forms do. Pretty basic stuff. But when I export the form to PDF, it exports ALL the records. I only want it to export the visible record of the form. Is this possible? It seems like it would be a pretty basic option, but am having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Apply filter to form so only that record is available. Or export a filtered query or report.

Answer (score 0):

Create a report with the data you want to print.

The report should be based on a query that filters the current record of the form. So you should create this query first.

Then place a button on the form that opens the report by VBA:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview
```

Then print the report.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to create a query.

However, do build the report - don't try and print the form, they are VERY messy to print.

So, you do this:

```
 If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False  ' save current reocrd
 
 Dim strReport          As String
 Dim strOutPutFile      As String
 strReport = "rptHotelsA"
 strOutPutFile = "c:\test\Hotel.pdf"
 
 DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewPreview, , "id = " & Me!ID, acHidden
 DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReport, acFormatPDF, strOutPutFile
 
 ' now close the report
 DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport
```

So, if we JUST use OutputTo, then all records will display. However, if you open the report with a filter (and hidden), then the "where" clause of the open report will only have the one current record (as the current form based on "ID").

Then, when we use outputto, then it will work against the open (but hidden report), and only output the one current record to the PDF.

Then when done, we close the hidden report.

You can also remove the acHidden, and in fact remove the part that exports the current record to that pdf file, and the report would then just display the one record, at which point, you could print, or even export to a pdf. So, then the code is this:

```
 If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False  ' save current reocrd
 
 Dim strReport          As String
 strReport = "rptHotelsA"
 
 DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewPreview, , "id = " & Me!ID
```

So, above will display the report, not export to PDF.